# In a maven webapp, How to take a property from CMD and update it into resources.properties

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

`When I am doing mvn clean install, I want to take a property from CMD using -DpropertyName=value and pass it to my resources.properties file through the pom.xml, but I am not able to do it. The resources.properties already contains some key value pairs and I have added propertyName = ${propertyName} so that I put the dynamic value in the file and retain the existing ones. I am using write-project-properties maven plugin with maven 3.x.I have added  
        ${propertyName} 
     to my pom. My resources.properties formed in the target WEB-INF folder contains the correct key value which is passed dynamically but it also contains the dependency names and their versions in key value pairs which is unexpected. And the resources.properties formed outside the WEB-INF in the target folder contains the unresolved key value pair which I am passing dynamically. Can someone help me in understanding what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post some example of result and expected result?

Comment: properties file after mvn clean install -DinstanceUrl=xxx 
com.yubico.version=0.14.0
carbon.kernel.registry.imp.pkg.version=[1.0.1, 2.0.0)
waffle-jna.imp.pkg.version.range=[1.6.wso2v1, 2.0)
axiom.version=1.2.11-wso2v10 and so on.....

but my properties files originally is  

remember.me=Remember me on this computer
signin.to.authenticate1=Please sign in to authenticate to
signin.to.authenticate2=as
profile=Profile :
cancel=Cancel
approve=Approve
continue=Continue
deny=Deny
approve.always=Approve Always
request.access.scope=requests access to and so on...